# Не могу получить h1 в заголовок

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

В content-скрипт или в background я получаю title, но как его передать или получить в открывающемся popup-окне со своим скриптом - в нем title страницы получить не получается (нужен h1 той страницы, на которой этот popup расширения открывается)?

UPD: В popup-окне я хочу передать title на сервер, но в этом же скрипте я не могу его получить стандартным скриптом, также в localStorage приходит undefined, хотя в целом на странице я сохранил title в localStorage другим скриптом (который content.js).

Устройство manifest'а следующее:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "name": "Название",
    "description": "Описание",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
            "css": ["ctyle.css"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
    "icons" : {
        "16" : "icon-16.png",
        "48" : "icon-48.png",
        "128" : "icon-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "нужный сайт/*",
        "storage"
  ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Название",
        "default_icon" : "icon-32.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, в чем заключается проблема, или укажите дополнительную информацию, чтобы понять, в чем именно состоит вопрос. В текущем виде практически невозможно точно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете. Посетите страницу «[как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)», чтобы понять, как следует оформлять вопросы.

Comment: Уточнил, теперь может быть понятнее.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, проголосуйте за него и отметьте как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У контента на странице и расширения разные `localStorage`, поэтому вы и не можете получить значение. Однако вам он и не нужен.

С помощью метода [`sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage) вы можете отправить команду для `content.js` из `popup.js`, а в `content.js` прочитать эту команду с помощью [`onMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onMessage) и выполнить с содержимым страницы определенные действия, вернув результат обратно в `popup.js`.

Поскольку у вас путаница с тем, что нужно получить (`h1` или `title`), я привожу пример для получения `title`, исправить который очень легко под ваши нужды.

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name":        "Demo extension",
  "description": "Playground for the stackoverflow needs",
  "version":     "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon":  "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://www.google.ru/*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js":      ["content.js"],
    "run_at":  "document_end"
  }]
}
```

**`popup.html`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="title" name="title" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`popup.js`**

```
// Заносим значение title в input
function setTitleInfo(title) {
  document.getElementById('title').value = title;
}

// Получение текущей вкладки
function getCurrentTab() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true, // Выбор активной вкладки
      currentWindow: true
    }, function (tabs) {
      resolve(tabs[0]);
    });
  });
}

// Отправка запроса к content.js после получения текущей вкладки
getCurrentTab().then(function (tab) {
  var currentTabId = tab.id;

  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, {
    action: 'TitleInfo' // Уникальное имя для нашего события
  }, setTitleInfo);     // Функция setTitleInfo будет выполнена после ответа content.js
});
```

**`content.js`**

```
// Подписка на события
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, response) {
  // Ждем события с определенным именем
  if ((msg.action === 'TitleInfo')) {
    // Возвращаем результат вычислений
    response(parseTitle());
  }
});

function parseTitle() {
  var title = document.querySelector('title');
  if (title) {
    return title.textContent;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы очень помогли!

Comment: VenZell, к слову, title возвращается как HTMLInputElement, а как получить строку (обычный текст)?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, тогда `title.value`.

Comment: var title = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  if (title) {
    return title.value;
  } - возвращается "undefined", даже если h1 есть.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov `var title = document.querySelector("h1"); if (title) { return title.textContent; }`

Comment: Все равно HTMLInputElement.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, я сейчас гадаю на кофейной гуще. Я не вижу страницы (или кода), которую вы парсите. Вот, посмотрите, такой код работает: https://jsfiddle.net/3eLmr1qn/

Comment: В итоге свой код использования h1 вставил не туда - спасибо еще раз, вы очень помогли!